# Swift Run Anyway Dialog : how to correct this?

Tags: swift

I moved a Swift project to a new drive and run it. I get this message in a dialog:

[image]

The original directory that the project resided in no longer exists, so clearly the scheme that was created for it is stuck looking for it, and is showing me this.

It seems like editing the scheme is needed, but I don't know where to start with that, or what implications it has....

When I run, it seems normal, so presumably there's no dependency here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that the working directory for the "Authentication 2" scheme does not exist. A "scheme" is the thing that you can select by using the dropdown menu next to the run destination:

[image]

For example, I have a scheme called "Foo" as shown above.

I would suggest selecting your "Authentication 2" scheme, and go to "Edit Scheme..." and change your working directory to something that does exist.

The dialog that opens when you click "Edit Scheme..." looks like this:

[image]

You should select "Run" on the left pane, and go to the "Options" tab.

From my experiments, it seems like if you "Run Anyway", the working directory will be set to a default one (as if you did not check the "Use custom working directory" checkbox).

Comment: yep, that was it... I just did not see that working directory, despite having been there, and ended up looking for some kind of configuration file... makes sense, and problem is gone. Gracias.